# How to automate a dplyr function call with a purrr function or a loop

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to automate a function call, so that I can produce one data frame by rotating in dependent variables such as x, y, and z and using various combinations of grouping variables such as year and race or separately, year, race, and city.

In more detail.

In my minimal example, I have three dependent variables, *x,y,z*. I also have several grouping variables. For each call, I need to count the number of 1’s. I also need to add a new column which contains string values which reflect the dependent variable that was used.

I was able to write a function that produces the counts when I specify the two grouping variables and the dependent variable. In the real problem, for each of about a dozen dependent variables, I will have to group in a number of different ways. I may have one, two, or three grouping variables.
Outside of the function, I added the character column that gives information on what the variables were. I think that inside the function I should have a case_when()statement that says something like:

```
case_when({{var1}} == 'x' ~ "This is the first",  
{{var1}} == 'y' ~ "Second one",  
{{var1}} == 'z' ~ "Third shot")
```

Then I used rbind to combine my results.

I have a working function and I can add the string column.

My end result needs to be a data frame. I am training the end user, a beginning R programmer, to use my code. So simplicity is preferred even if that means using a few functions.

I read:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html
https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#purrr-style

However, I do not know how to automate the process so that a different user can do one function call (or maybe two or three). If I do this interactively, there will be hundreds of combinations of variables.
I assume that this can be done with a loop or with a purr function, but I was unable to figure it out.

```
library(tidyverse)  
set.seed(2021)  
numRows = 1000

df1 = data.frame(year = sample(2010:2013, size = numRows, replace = TRUE),
             race = sample(c('white', 'black', 'Asian', 'Hispanic'), size = numRows, replace = TRUE),
             city = sample(c('Oakland', 'Berkeley','Fremont'), size = numRows, replace = TRUE),
             young = sample(c(1,2,NA), size = numRows, replace = TRUE),
             old = sample(c(1,2,NA), size = numRows, replace = TRUE),
             x = sample(x = c(1,2, NA), size = numRows, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.7, .2, .1)),
             y = sample(x = c(1,2, NA), size = numRows, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.7, .2, .1)),
             z = sample(x = c(1,2, NA), size = numRows, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.7, .2, .1)))

df1$year = factor(df1$year)
df1$race = factor(df1$race)
df1$city = factor(df1$city)

# Working code
compute_num02 = function(grp1, grp2, var1) {
res_num = df1 %>%
filter(!is.na({{var1}}), {{var1}} == 1  )  %>%  
group_by({{grp1}}, {{grp2}}, .drop = FALSE) %>% summarize(counts = n()) %>% 
select({{grp1}},{{grp2}},counts) %>% as.data.frame()
res_num 
}

# Completing the code interactively
res1 = compute_num02(year, city,x)
res1$Note = "This is the first"

res2 = compute_num02(year, city,y)
res2$Note = "Second one"

res3 = compute_num02(year, city,z)
res3$Note = "Third shot"
result_final = rbind(res1,res2,res3)
result_final
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to pass as quoted or unquoted, we could convert to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`) .  Here, we are changing only the 'var1' part, the grouping columns can also be changed (if we want to do loop more than 1 inputs, use `map2` (for 2 variable inputs) or `pmap` (for >= 2))

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
compute_num02 = function(dat, grp1, grp2, var1) {
    # // convert the inputs to symbol
    grp1 <- rlang::ensym(grp1)
    grp2 <- rlang::ensym(grp2)
    var1 <- rlang::ensym(var1)
    # // evaluate with !!
    res_num <- dat %>%
        filter(!is.na(!! var1),  !! var1 == 1  )  %>%  
        group_by(!! grp1, !! grp2, .drop = FALSE) %>%
        summarize(counts = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
        select(!! grp1, !! grp2, counts) %>% 
        as.data.frame()
      res_num 
}
```

Loop over the 'x', 'y', 'z in `map`, apply the `compute_num02`

```
map_dfr(c('x', 'y', 'z'), 
      ~ compute_num02(df1, year, city,  !!.x), .id = 'Note')
```

-output

```
#   Note year     city counts
#1     1 2010 Berkeley     62
#2     1 2010  Fremont     58
#3     1 2010  Oakland     57
#4     1 2011 Berkeley     47
#5     1 2011  Fremont     48
#6     1 2011  Oakland     54
#7     1 2012 Berkeley     55
#8     1 2012  Fremont     70
#9     1 2012  Oakland     48
#10    1 2013 Berkeley     52
#11    1 2013  Fremont     61
#12    1 2013  Oakland     65
#13    2 2010 Berkeley     66
#14    2 2010  Fremont     62
#15    2 2010  Oakland     56
#16    2 2011 Berkeley     55
#17    2 2011  Fremont     55
#18    2 2011  Oakland     55
#19    2 2012 Berkeley     51
#20    2 2012  Fremont     65
#21    2 2012  Oakland     48
#22    2 2013 Berkeley     44
#23    2 2013  Fremont     54
#24    2 2013  Oakland     71
#25    3 2010 Berkeley     67
#26    3 2010  Fremont     63
#27    3 2010  Oakland     49
#28    3 2011 Berkeley     59
#29    3 2011  Fremont     60
#30    3 2011  Oakland     59
#31    3 2012 Berkeley     61
#32    3 2012  Fremont     64
#33    3 2012  Oakland     43
#34    3 2013 Berkeley     47
#35    3 2013  Fremont     58
#36    3 2013  Oakland     64
```